# Breadth First Search in graphs using queues

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I think my code has mistakes and I don't know the reasons.

The graph is:
[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOiMw.jpg)

The output is:

[Output of the BFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYbqr.png)

> The outputs is: 1->2->4->5

But it is incorrect because the correct answer is:

> 1->2->4->5->3

My code is written in Java and I have the classes NodoG (which represents the node of the graph), Grafo (which represents the graph) and Principal (where I do the operations).

In addition, I do not take into account the weights of the edges, I only consider the order that the adjacent ones are introduced in the respective node.

For example:

- 1-> 2 with weight 3: I write it first
- 1-> 4 with weight 10: I put it second
- 1-> 5 with weight 12: I put it third

And I do with each node. However, if there are no neighbors for a node, I won't write it as data.

```
public class NodoG {
    private int dato;
    boolean visitado;
    List<NodoG> adyacentes;

    public NodoG(int dato){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.visitado = false;
        this.adyacentes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public boolean isVisitado() {
        return visitado;
    }

    public void setVisitado(boolean visitado) {
        this.visitado = visitado;
    }

    public List<NodoG> getAdyacentes() {
        return adyacentes;
    }

    public void setAdyacentes(ArrayList<NodoG> adyacentes) {
        this.adyacentes = adyacentes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return (dato + "->");
    } 
 }
```

My another Class: Grafo

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Queue;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Grafo {
        private List<NodoG> nodoGrafo;
        
        public Grafo(){
            nodoGrafo = new ArrayList<NodoG>();
        }
    
        public List<NodoG> getNodoGrafo() {
            return nodoGrafo;
        }
    
        public void setNodoGrafo(ArrayList<NodoG> nodoGrafo) {
            this.nodoGrafo = nodoGrafo;
        }
        
        public void insertarNodoG(){
            System.out.println("Write data: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("->");
            int valor = entrada.nextInt();
            NodoG nodo = new NodoG(valor);
            nodoGrafo.add(nodo);       
        }
        
        public NodoG buscarNodoGrafo(int n1){
            NodoG nodo = null;
            for (NodoG nodoGrafo1 : nodoGrafo) {
                if(nodoGrafo1.getDato() == n1){
                    nodo = nodoGrafo1;
                }
            }
            return nodo;
        }
        
        public void insertarAdyacente(){
            System.out.println("Write the data of the graph's node: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("->");
            int valor = entrada.nextInt();
            NodoG nodo = buscarNodoGrafo(valor);
            if(nodo!=null){
                System.out.println("Write the data of the adjacent: ");
                System.out.print("->");
                int dato = entrada.nextInt();
                NodoG nuevo = new NodoG(dato);
                nodo.getAdyacentes().add(nuevo);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("->This node doesn't exist.");
            }
        }
        
        public void busquedaAmplitud(){
            System.out.println("Write the initial node: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            int dato = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            NodoG inicio = buscarNodoGrafo(dato);
            if(inicio!=null){
                Queue<NodoG> cola = new LinkedList<NodoG>();
                
                cola.add(inicio);
                inicio.setVisitado(true);
                while(!cola.isEmpty()){
                  //  System.out.println("size: "+cola.size());
                    NodoG elem = cola.poll();
                    //System.out.println("--------------");
                    System.out.print("->" + elem.getDato());
                    //System.out.println("--------------");
                    List<NodoG> ady = elem.getAdyacentes();
                    for (int i = 0;i<ady.size();i++) {
                        NodoG ady1 = ady.get(i);
                        if(ady1!= null && !ady1.isVisitado()){
                            cola.add(ady1);
                            ady1.setVisitado(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("This node doesn't exist.");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

My last class: Principal

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grafo G = new Grafo();
        int opc;
        System.out.println("=========================");
        System.out.println("BFS");
        System.out.println("=========================");
        System.out.println("¿How many nodes does the graph have?: ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cant = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Write the data of the nodes: ");
        for(int i=0;i<cant;i++){
            G.insertarNodoG();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");
        System.out.println("Adjacent of the node");
        System.out.println("===================================");
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the node you want to write an adjacent:");
            G.insertarAdyacente();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("¿Do you want to write another adjacent?: (Yes: 1) (No: Any number) -> ");
            opc = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        }while(opc == 1);
        do{
            System.out.println("==========================");
            System.out.println("BFS: ");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            G.busquedaAmplitud();
            System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
            //restartnodes() //To restar the boolean values of the nodes
        System.out.println("¿Do you want to use another node? (Yes: 1) (No: Any number)->");
            opc = entrada.nextInt();
        }while(opc==1);
    }
}
```

Please, can someone help me? Also, I need to know how to restart the boolean values of the nodes.

Comment: What wrong happens? What's your input and what output is supposed to happen, but what output actually happens instead?

Comment: My inputs are the the values of the nodes and the adjacents in the first image (This is the graph) and my output is 1->2->4->5, but it is incorrect because the correct answer is 1->2->4->5->3

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pop()` instead of `poll()`? Have you ever considered a standard format instead of re-entering the numbers all the time? Something like [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/resources/) has Java language bindings.

Comment: I use `poll()` because I return a node. About the standard that you wrote, I don't understand at all. I'm a beginner in Java. I use Netbeans 8.2. But, I need to implement this algorithm in Java because it's one of the requirements.

Comment: I guess `poll` and `pop` are different only in the case of an empty list in Java, which you check for anyway; never mind. Is the `cola` giving you expected results when printing it?

Comment: Yes, they are different, but  `poll()` is inside the loop `while`, so I think is correct, but I'm not sure. About `cola`, it don't print the results that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Made two fixes on the code. First of all, your `insertarAdyacente()` function was not working properly. Because you created a new node instead of finding the already created node with the given data. You can find the correct version below.

```
        public void insertarAdyacente(){
            System.out.println("Write the data of the graph's node: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("->");
            int valor = entrada.nextInt();
            NodoG nodo = buscarNodoGrafo(valor);
            if(nodo!=null){
                System.out.println("Write the data of the adjacent: ");
                System.out.print("->");
                int dato = entrada.nextInt();
                NodoG nuevo = buscarNodoGrafo(dato);  // fixed here.
                nodo.getAdyacentes().add(nuevo);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("->This node doesn't exist.");
            }
        }
```

Secondly, I think giving a `isVisited` field to all of the nodes rather than simply creating an array of booleans within the BFS function seems to be a bad practice. But I didn't want to change the logic you are applying, rather I created a new function within the `Grafo` so that whenever we want to call `busquedaAmplitud()`, it sets all visiteds to be False.

```
        public void setVisitadoFalse() {
            for(NodoG node: this.getNodoGrafo()) {
                node.setVisitado(false);
            }
        }
        public void busquedaAmplitud(){
            this.setVisitadoFalse();   // No one is visited at the beginning.
            System.out.println("Write the initial node: ");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            int dato = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            NodoG inicio = buscarNodoGrafo(dato);
            if(inicio!=null){
                Queue<NodoG> cola = new LinkedList<NodoG>();
                
                cola.add(inicio);
                inicio.setVisitado(true);
                while(!cola.isEmpty()){
                    NodoG elem = cola.poll();
                    //System.out.println("--------------");
                    System.out.print("->" + elem.getDato());
                    //System.out.println("--------------");
                    List<NodoG> ady = elem.getAdyacentes();


                    for (int i = 0;i<ady.size();i++) {
                        NodoG ady1 = ady.get(i);
                        if(ady1!= null && !ady1.isVisitado()){
                            cola.add(ady1);
                            ady1.setVisitado(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("This node doesn't exist.");
            }
        }
```